# Web sockets, fleck, send message from client to server

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

*Using Fleck package for server.

I have two separate console apps:

web socket server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
{
  //list of client sockets
  List<IWebSocketConnection> sockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();

  var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://x.x.x.x:80");
  server.Start(socket =>
  {
    socket.OnOpen = () =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
      sockets.Add(socket); //add client socket to list
    };

    socket.OnClose = () =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected!");
      sockets.Remove(socket); //remove client socket from list
    };

    socket.OnMessage = message =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Client says: " + message);
    }; 
  });

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and client app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ClientWebSocket client = new ClientWebSocket();
  client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://10.92.84.183:80"), CancellationToken.None).Wait();
  Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
}
```

**How can I send a message from the client app to the server; and then for the server to console.writeline that message?**

**Also, when the client connects to the server, the server executes socket.OnOpen(), however when the client is closed, the server doesn't execute socket.OnClose(), any ideas?**

Comment: See the msdn examples that uses socket.  It looks like your ClientWebSocket inherits the socket class so you can replace the socket in the example with your WebSocket : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/listening-with-sockets

Comment: @jdweng ClientWebSocket inherits the WebSocket class not socket, and I don't see anything about sending a message to a server on that url. Also do you know why the socket.OnClose() isn't executing but the socket.OnOpen() does? Thanks

Comment: See following example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Connecting-with-WebSockets-643b10ab  There is an Async Send method.